# AngularJS controllers in separate files and async loadin - RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am newbee in Angular so I hope you will help me.

I want to implement this structure in my future app:

```
 app/
 ----- components/
 ---------- home/
 --------------- homeController.js
 --------------- homeService.js
 --------------- homeView.html
```

I want to use RequireJS to load scripts asynchronously so I copied code from Angular Seed to do that and modified it:

```
$script([
    '<?php echo base_url('assets/v2/mobile/js/angular' . $minified . '.js'); ?>',
    '<?php echo base_url('assets/v2/mobile/js/angular-route' . $minified . '.js'); ?>',
    '<?php echo base_url('assets/v2/mobile/js/angular-animate' . $minified . '.js'); ?>',
    '<?php echo base_url('assets/v2/mobile/js/angular-aria' . $minified . '.js'); ?>',
    '<?php echo base_url('/v2/m_resources/js/login/controller'); ?>',
    '<?php echo base_url('/v2/m_resources/js/app/login'); ?>',              
], function () {
    // when all is done, execute bootstrap angular application
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['npLogin']);
});
```

If I put controller in the app file everything works fine but I if I separate them than I facing error which says:

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'npLogin' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I am gassing that it is because if it loads controller file first then `npLogin` is not initialized yet.

The app file:

```
angular.module('npLogin', [
    'ngRoute',
])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
     .when('/', {
         templateUrl: '/m_resources/view/app/login.html',
         controller: 'NpLoginController'
     });
}]);
```

Controller file:

```
angular.module('npLogin')
.controller('NpLoginController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log(1);
}]);
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** OK I found solution:

I had to create another module and inject it as a dependency to main app.

// I added "use-strict too"

APP:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('npLogin.controller', [])
            .controller('NpLoginController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                    console.log(1);
                }])
            ;
})();
```

Controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('npLogin.controller', [])
            .controller('NpLoginController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                    console.log(1);
                }])
            ;
})();
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP guru, so I may be off base, but when I needed to create a PHP/Angular app I kept the PHP 100% server side and only used Angular for the front end. In which case the angular seed async wouldn't need modified.

Comment: Do you have an `ng-app` directive in your markup? If so, that will cause Angular to bootstrap the application and that can only be done once. Since you are delay-loading your Angular components, you need to wait to bootstrap until all of them are loaded (which is what your first code snippet is supposed to do).

Comment: @JackA. According to Angular Seed I should not use ng-app directive:https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/index-async.html

Comment: @TjGienger My app is specific and I have to keep my files loaded by PHP but it is not a problem.